# Nest authentication unstable

Tags: java, android, ssl, firebase, nest-api

I used the **auth(token, new Firebase.AuthListener())** function of firebase to authentication and access data,
and I found that it sometimes spend long time(more than 5 minutes) to finished authentication.
But this situation does not happened few month ago.

The Firebase library I downloaded from https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/firebase-client-libraries ,
so my firebase library version is 1.1.1.
Had anyone happen this kind of situation?

I had try to use **authWithCustomToken**(...) to replace the **auth**(...), but it not work.
How do I used this function to authentication in nest?

And I found that the firebase added SSL to their protocol, is it the reson that caused above situation?

I download a firebase.js from
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2012-07-27-firebase-now-supports-ssl.html , but I don't know how to use this file
to create a *.crt or *.cer file, does anyone can help me?

/******************************* Update ***********************************/

The following are sample code as follow:

access_token I already get from nest via http request,

```
String Access_Token_URL = "https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token";
URL u = new URL(Access_Token_URL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

String cmd = "code="+pincode+"&client_id=" + Client_ID + "&client_secret="+ Client_secret +"&grant_type=authorization_code";
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

wr.writeBytes(cmd); 
wr.flush();
wr.close(); // flush and close                  

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
      //do something
}
reader.close();
JSONObject stock_data = new JSONObject(line);
access_token = stock_data.getString("access_token");   //access_token="c.W6o3HEpUe3a..........";
```

and I use the access_token in auth() function,

```
String DataBase_URL = "https://developer-api.nest.com";
Firebase myDataBase = new Firebase(DataBase_URL);
myDataBase.auth(access_token, new Firebase.AuthListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAuthError(FirebaseError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "AuthErro: " + arg0.getMessage());
        //to do something...
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthRevoked(FirebaseError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "AuthRevoked: " + arg0.getMessage());
        //to do something...
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthSuccess(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "AuthSuccess " + arg0.toString());
        //to do something...
    }
});
```

It spends more than 5 minutes to got the **AuthSuccess** message, is the behavior correct?
If not, how should I modify my code?

Comment: I don't think SSL is related. Regardless, you don't have to do anything to use SSL. Only Nest had to create a certificate on their side.

Comment: Please write up a small code sample that reproduces your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve